# Passing JFrame object Class as a value in HashMap in java

Tags: java, hashmap, jframe

In my project there are about 10 "JFrame"s.
Now I want to put this objects of "JFrame"s as value into a map. and every time I need this objects get from the map.

for example:

```
Jframe1 jframe_1 = new Jframe1();  
Jframe2 jframe_2 = new Jframe2();   
Jframe3 jframe_3 = new Jframe3();   
Jframe4 jframe_4 = new Jframe4(); 



map.put("1",jframe_1);  
map.put("2",jframe_2);  
map.put("3",jframe_3);  
map.put("4",jframe_4);
```

Note that I want to use any fields and methods that are in class when I get a value from map.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *any fields and methods that are in class*. You can only use the same key that you used when inserting into the map to retrieve.

Comment: for example in Jframe1 class there is method test(). i mean after i get jframe_1 from map i run method test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the value you get from the map.

```
Jframe1 jframe_1 =(Jframe1) map.get("1");
```

and then use whatever fields you want to use

```
jframe_1.start();
```

Comment: Thanks.I knew it . But i want to know is another way without casting?